# Looping directories and saving data

Tags: php, arrays, directory

I have a directory called images.  Lets say the path is

```
somepath.com/images/
```

Within my images directory is a number of folders.  So lets say I have

```
somepath.com/images/folder1
somepath.com/images/folder2
```

Within each of these folders are a number of images.  So lets say I have

```
somepath.com/images/folder1/img1.png
somepath.com/images/folder1/img2.png
somepath.com/images/folder2/img1.png
somepath.com/images/folder2/img2.png
```

I am trying to build up an array containing all of this data.  I would expect the array to look something like this

```
array:2 [▼
  "directories" => array:1 [▼
    "Name" => "folder1"
  ]
  "files" => array:14 [▼
    0 => array:1 [▼
      "Name" => "img1.png"
    ]
    2 => array:1 [▼
      "Name" => "img2.png"
    ]
  ]
]
array:2 [▼
  "directories" => array:1 [▼
    "Name" => "folder2"
  ]
  "files" => array:14 [▼
    0 => array:1 [▼
      "Name" => "img1.png"
    ]
    2 => array:1 [▼
      "Name" => "img2.png"
    ]
  ]
]
```

This way, I can see there is a folder1 and inside of this is img1 and img2.  To produce this array, I am currently scanning the base directory to get the folder names.  I then loop the folders in order to get the file names.  This is what I currently have

```
$data = array();
$directories = scandir("somepath.com/images/");

foreach($directories as $directory){
    if($directory=='.' or $directory=='..' ){
        continue;
    } else{
        $data["directories"] = array(
            "Name" => $directory
        );

        $dirFiles = scandir("somepath.com/images/" . $directory);
        foreach($dirFiles as $file){
            if($file=='.' or $file=='..' ){
                continue;
            } else {
                $data["files"][] = array(
                    "Name" => $file
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I am having at the moment is the first directory data being overwritten.  Additionally, the array I am left with seems to have all 4 images for folder2.  How can I alter what I have
in order to produce the desired output?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the structure is slightly different by using the array index as the folder name you can use this code: [Deep recursive array of directory structure in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952263/deep-recursive-array-of-directory-structure-in-php)
 which would produce an array like:

```
array:2 [
  "folder1" => array:2 [
    "img1.png",
    "img2.png"
  ],
  "folder2" => array:2 [
    "img1.png",
    "img2.png"
  ]
]
```

The code will also traverse multiple sub-directories, so given the structure in the first block it would also create a result like the second block:

```
somepath.com/images/folder1/img1.png
somepath.com/images/folder1/img2.png
somepath.com/images/folder1/subfolder1/img1.png
somepath.com/images/folder1/subfolder1/img2.png
somepath.com/images/folder2/img1.png
somepath.com/images/folder2/img2.png
somepath.com/images/folder2/subfolder1/img1.png
somepath.com/images/folder2/subfolder1/img2.png
```

-- yields:

```
array:2 [
  "folder1" => array:3 [
    "subfolder1" => array:2 [
      "img1.png",
      "img2.png"
    ]
    "img1.png",
    "img2.png"
  ],
  "folder2" => array:3 [
    "subfolder1" => array:2 [
      "img1.png",
      "img2.png"
    ]
    "img1.png",
    "img2.png"
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out the `FolderScanner` Class Found here. Perhaps it does the Trick for you. You can just include it in your Project and work with it like so:

```
    <?php
        require_once "FolderScanner.php";

        // EXTRACT ALL IMAGE FILES IN "IMAGES" DIRECTORY 
        // REPLACE THE PATH ACCORDING TO YOUR PROJECT'S STRUCTURE  
        $pathToImagesDirectory  = "somepath.com/images/"; 
        $imgFilesInImagesDir    = FolderScanner::scan_folder_for_image_files($pathToImagesDirectory); 

        // $THE $imgFilesInImagesDir CONTAINS THE STRUCTURED DATA...
        // var_dump($imgFilesInImagesDir);
```